# Disadvantages of using empty div tags for styling purposes?

Tags: css, html, background-image

Are there any disadvantages (aside from muddier code) to using empty elements on a page simply for styling purposes?

For instance, using some empty `<div>`s with different texture background images to lie fixed behind page content.

The obvious one is that you're technically blurring the separation between structure and presentation layers.  If I'm ok with that aspect of it, I'm just wondering if this poses any SEO, performance, or other issues.

Any links or evidence that point me in either direction would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: If you're OK with that aspect of it, I don't think there are any more compelling disadvantages.

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a solution that doesn't make that line blur, but for a few instances, I think I'm ok, yeah.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically speaking, I would think not. If only it is a few empty elements. But instead of using empty DIVs to sport multiple backgrounds, why not just use CSS3's Backgrounds and Borders Module? In this level 3 module, you can specify multiple backgrounds for one element, and I assume in your case the body element.

You can learn more about these here: http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-css3-multiple-backgrounds/

For more information regarding the DIV element and it's correlation with SEO, check out this link: http://blog.ucvhost.com/advantages-of-div-tag-from-seo-prospective

Comment: Well, you honestly want to have as many, if not any, empty tags in your HTML Document. Because if the element provides no sort of readable content, then the tag is rendered useless. Thanks for the +1. +1 to you for the question that other people need to understand as well.

Comment: For more information regarding the DIV element and it's correlation with SEO, check out this link: http://blog.ucvhost.com/advantages-of-div-tag-from-seo-prospective/ .

Comment: Thank you Scrimothy, I have added the last comment to the Answer. Hope I helped! :)